# unterminated parenthetical : JS upload file

Tags: javascript, file

I'm trying to reproduce this : https://codepen.io/adamlaki/pen/VYpewx

It's for making a good design to an input file

But I have this error on my website :

> SyntaxError: unterminated parenthetical

This is my code :

```
<script>
   $("form").on("change", ".file-upload-field", function(){
   $(this).parent(".file-upload-wrapper").attr("data-text", $(this).val().replace(/.*(\/|\)/, "") );
  });
</script>
```

(i'm adding my code thanks to this)

```
$content .= '<script>
  $("form").on("change", ".file-upload-field", function(){
  $(this).parent(".file-upload-wrapper").attr("data-text", $(this).val().replace(/.*(\/|\\)/, "") );
  });
 </script>';
```

What do I miss ? Cause the syntax looks good

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a runnable snippet? I can’t seem to make your code produce that error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
replace(/.*(\/|\)/, "")
           X    X
```

I have marked the parentheticals in your regex with X above.

The first one is a real `(` which starts a group.

The second one is an **escaped** `\)` which is treated as data.

There is no real `)` to end the group.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed it to                         **$(this).parent(".file-upload-wrapper").attr("data-text", $(this).val().replace(/.*(\/|\\)/, "") );**